# get OSC info back from the server

Tags: server, client, osc, info

I am using pyOSC and trying to get data from the OSC server back to the client. One of the default handlers is for '/info'. In the OSC code I see the following comment in serverInfo_handler:

```
    a Message-handler function may return None, but it could also return an OSCMessage (or OSCBundle),
    which then gets sent back to the client.

    This handler returns a reply to the client, which can contain various bits of information
    about this server, depending on the first argument of the received OSC-message:
```

But how to get this info in the client? There is no read or receive function in the client...

Answer (score 0):

I found out the easiest way to do this is to have both an OSC client and server running on the target machine. This way the server part can process the messages and the client part can send data back. This can be done in one program by creating a server and a client thread.

BTW, I switched to python-osc now, quite easy to use.